# int object not iterable when concatenating a list?

Tags: python

```
def get_fail_pass_average(number_list):
    for number in number_list:
        under_50_list = []
        over_50_list = []
        if number >= 50:
            over_50_list += list(number)
        else:
            under_50_list = under_50_list + list(number)
```

Hi there,

For this code, I am trying to add a number to the over_50_list if that number if over 50. However, I get an error message stating that the int object is not interable. But aren't I adding a list with another list? How can that produce an error?

(I haven't included all the code here; I'm just trying to understand why I can't add these two lists. The aim of this code is to produce a list which gives the average of the over 50 and at 50 marks and under 50 marks)

Comment: `over_50_list.append(number)`, ``under_50_list.append(number)``

Comment: that is not what OP wants

Comment: Did you check the documentation on `list()` before asking the question?

Comment: `IndentationError` .. please [edit] and fix. Also add the call of this function with demodata to make it a [mre] AND add the Stacktrace of your error - throw in some `print()` statements of your variables to debug the next upcoming error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You problem isn't adding things to the existing `list`s. It's calling the `list()` constructor on a number. That doesn't work; `list()` expects to receive an iterable that it converts to a `list`, but numbers are not iterable.

You really just want the `list.append` method to add single elements to the end of the `list`, e.g.:

```
over_50_list.append(number)
```

but if you insist on making single element temporary `list`s for the purpose, or really like the `+=` syntax (which expects an iterable, just like `list()` itself does), you could do:

```
over_50_list += [number]
```

which makes a `list` literal containing a single value, which can then be passed to `+=` for concatenation (it's just less efficient when you're only adding a single value at a time, creating and destroying temporary `list`s unnecessarily, which `append` avoids).

Once you've fixed that, you'll find the `list`s never have more than one element; that's because you replace them with a new empty `list` each time you loop. Move the definitions above/outside the `for` loop so you only make one new `list` for each, then build them element by element.

Answer (score 0):

Change the code to if you want to add all the numbers separately as lists:

```
def get_fail_pass_average(number_list):
    for number in number_list:
        under_50_list = []
         over_50_list = []
        if number >= 50:
            over_50_list += [number]
        else:
             under_50_list += [number]
```

But, if you want to add the numbers to the lists directly, you can do:

```
def get_fail_pass_average(number_list):
    for number in number_list:
        under_50_list = []
         over_50_list = []
        if number >= 50:
            over_50_list.append(number)
        else:
             under_50_list.append(number])
```

Simply, you are not allowed to do `list(int)`